# Who's Going To Be At Convention X?

Tags: discussion

This is an experimental question.

**Reasons**

I go to five or six gaming cons each year, and I would like a way to find out who else from this site might be attending, so I can meet people face to face. I think this would both be fun and have some promotional value. Thus, I wanted to find out if meta is a useful place for that organization.

**Rules**

If you're going to be at a given convention, post it as an answer. Give the basic info about the convention (location, date, maybe anything interesting about the con) and link to their Web site. If someone else is going, either edit the original answer or add a comment.

Comment: Maybe voting up answers to cons that you think you might attend would be good.

Answer (score 2):

#### NY/NJ 2011: Dreamation, Dexcon & I-Con

Three cons in this area:

- Dreamation (Feb 24-27th 2011) and Dexcon (July 6-10th 2011) in the NJ area
- I-Con (April 15-17th, 2011) in NY.

#### Attendees

- [RMorrisey](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/188/rmorrisey): all.  Maybe GASPcon too.
- Jmstar: Dreamation
- [Jadasc](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50/jadasc): DexCon.

Answer (score 1):

**GASPcon 11**

[GASPcon 11](http://www.gaspgamer.com/gasp_con/gaspcon.html) is taking place November 12th-14th, 2010, in Pittsburgh, PA. It's a good regional convention, with a strong story game track and a strong Living Forgotten Realms track, plus a lot of other games. There's not much of a dealer's room. It's good to make hotel reservations early, since there's a Pittsburgh Steelers home game which tends to cause the hotel to fill up.

**Attendees**

- [Bryant](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24/bryant)

Comment: Ooh, I never heard of this one. I might check it out.

Answer (score 1):

### [GenCon Indy](http://www.gencon.com/2011/indy/default.aspx)

GenCon. It's the big one. Indianapolis, Indiana. August 4-7.

> Gen Con Indy is the original, longest running, best attended, gaming convention in the world. For over 41 years, Gen Con Indy has been setting the trend and breaking records. Last year, more than 30,000 unique attendees experienced Gen Con Indy. The biggest complaint we hear is that there is simply too much to do, see, and experience.

### Attendees

- [gomad](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/696/gomad)
- [Jadasc](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50/jadasc)

Answer (score 0):

**The Grand Masquerade II**

The [Grand Masquerade](http://www.thegrandmasquerade.com/) (September 15-18, 2011; New Orleans, LA) is White Wolf's pan-Vampire™ fandom convention. It's got a strong live-action focus, but there's a full track for tabletop World of Darkness games and the Vampire CCG. There's reputedly a big announcement on Friday night — probably concerning the new MMO offering — and a few of the enormous parties that White Wolf is known for.

**Attendees**

- [Jadasc](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50/Jadasc)